# How does C compiler handle bit-field?

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

The following `bit field` sample code is from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bit-fields-c/). It claims better storage efficiency. But I am wondering how the compiler handles the bit field?

I guess the C compiler **HAS TO** generate extra instructions for bit-wise manipulation. So although the data size is reduced, the code size is increased.

Any one familiar with the C compiler could shed some light?

```
#include <stdio.h>

// A space optimized representation of date
struct date
{
   // d has value between 1 and 31, so 5 bits
   // are sufficient
   unsigned int d: 5;

   // m has value between 1 and 12, so 4 bits
   // are sufficient
   unsigned int m: 4;

   unsigned int y;
};

int main()
{
   printf("Size of date is %d bytes\n", sizeof(struct date));
   struct date dt = {31, 12, 2014};
   printf("Date is %d/%d/%d", dt.d, dt.m, dt.y);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could look at the generated assembler to find out.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks for reminding. How could I forget that...

Comment: It depends on your platform (underlying HW architecture + designated compiler), but in general - yes, the compiler most likely needs to add bit-wise operations (which typically result in larger code section and/or slower runtime execution).

Comment: BTW, "any one familiar with the C compiler" is somewhat contradictory to the fact that there are many C compilers (in contrast with a single C-language standard, for which you may "legitimately" use this notion).

Comment: Is this `unsigned int m: 4;` even correct syntactically?

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @barakmanos I've never seen that syntax, i.e. a colon between a variable name and its value...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: interestingly, plugging this precise example in gcc [makes the bitfield disappear completely](https://godbolt.org/g/Vyc8GW) (it plugs the values straight into `printf`).

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti: well, it's the bitfield syntax - deal with it. :o)

Comment: @MatteoItalia "deal with it." ? My was just a question based on the fact that I didn't know something. Stay calm dude.

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti: Look for `C bitfield` on your favorite search-engine...

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti: I'm sorry if I seemed rude, that wasn't intended; it just made me chuckle that someone was questioning if the very feature argument of the whole question was actually valid syntax.

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti: I think that what mateoitalia was trying to say is that asking `even correct` when [1. The OP is highly rated. 2. The question is well constructed. 3. There are several comments referring directly to the code.] seems somewhat aggressive (though I do not agree that replying to your comment in an aggressive manner is necessarily the correct approach in this case). I do think that you could have inferred from all of the above that this syntax is correct. Whenever I see some unfamiliar syntax (mostly in C++), I always "check the surrounding" before making any "accusations".

Comment: @barakmanos What are we talking about guys? Please, that was just a conversational question, come on. You're creating a storm where it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Nuncameesquecideti: Was only trying to interpret mateoitalia's comment, nothing beyond that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So although the data size is reduced, the code size is increased.

In general, this is correct: it's a trade-off between more compact storage vs faster access.

For example, this is what my compiler produces for the `printf` statement in your bitfield example:

```
    movq    _dt@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movzwl  (%rax), %edx
    movl    %edx, %esi
    andl    $31, %esi     ; -- extract the 5 bits representing day
    shrl    $5, %edx      ; -+ extract the four bits for the month
    andl    $15, %edx     ; /
    movl    4(%rax), %ecx ; -- year doesn't require any bit manipulation
    leaq    L_.str.1(%rip), %rdi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   _printf
```

For comparison, the same code when `date` is a simple `struct`:

```
    movq    _dt@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movl    (%rax), %esi  ; -- day
    movl    4(%rax), %edx ; -- month
    movl    8(%rax), %ecx ; -- year
    leaq    L_.str.1(%rip), %rdi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   _printf
```

All of this is of course compiler- and platform-specific.

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, the doc for bit fields says that this is just a 
recommendation for the compiler. The implementation is free
to choose real bits or some less efficient (space-wise) implementation.

Bit field is actually just a convenience syntax for working with bits.

But it turns out that embedded compilers tend to use real bit fields,
since working with bits is a very common task in embedded programming. 
And this, of course, must be documented with the compiler, if one wants
to use this feature.

Regarding complexity of the assembler, it makes sense that real bits
require more work from the assembler.